# execution stops after adding another loop (C, Project Hangman)

Tags: c, loops, execution

Hello stackoverflow community,
I am a newbie at coding and just had a 2 weeks courses in c.
We have to do a project and my project of choice was hangman.
Everything worked so far but after adding one more loop (for or while) to output the found letters  the execution stops after the input of a letter (so after line 68) and idk why.
i am on cygwin on win 7 btw.
Thanks a lot for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
unsigned sleep( unsigned seconds );
void Welcome()
{
      printf("      WELCOME\n"); 
      //sleep(1);
}
void showLogo() 
{

      printf("            TO\n"); 
      //sleep(2);
      printf("--------------------------------------------  _______\n");
      printf("| H  H   A   N   N  GGGG M   M   A   N   N |  |/   | \n");
      printf("| H  H  A A  NN  N G     MM MM  A A  NN  N |  |/   | \n");
      printf("| HHHH AAAAA N N N G  GG M M M AAAAA N N N |  |    O \n");
      printf("| H  H A   A N  NN G   G M   M A   A N  NN |  |   \\|/\n");
      printf("| H  H A   A N   N  GGG  M   M A   A N   N |  |    | \n");
      printf("--------------------------------------------  |   / \\\n");
      printf("                                           __|_________\n\n");
}

void RandomWords()
{   
//sleep(2);
FILE *h =  fopen("words.txt","r");
int zeichen = 0;
int anzahl_worte = 0;
if( fscanf(h, "%d\n", &anzahl_worte)!=1) //anzahl_worte(= number of words) been read out of words.txt
{
    printf("No valid word file. Missing number of words.");
}
char** var = calloc(anzahl_worte, sizeof(char*));
for(int i = 0; i < anzahl_worte; i++)
{
    var[i] = calloc(30, sizeof(char)); //every array has now 20 places free
    fscanf(h,"%49s", var[i]); //arrays are being filled with words

}
int zufall = rand() % anzahl_worte;
strcpy(var[0], var[zufall]);//arrays been chosen by random  
zeichen = strlen(var[0]);   
printf("Anzahl der gesuchten Buchstaben: %d\n", zeichen);
printf("Das gesuchte Wort ist übrigens : %s\n", var[0]);
fflush(stdout);
char strich[30];
char* p[30];

for(int i = 0; i < zeichen; i++) //"_" for every letter 
{   
    strich[i] = '_';
    p[i] = &strich[i];
    printf("%c ", strich[i]);
                                //every "_" has a Pointer
                                //should later be replaced with a letter
}
//printf("\n%c\n", *p[0]);
char* letter[1];  //found letter will be saved here
int k = 0;  //position of the found letter in the word
//char** position = calloc(zeichen, sizeof(char**));
char* lpointer; //Addresse of the found letter 

printf("\nGeben Sie bitte Ihren Buchstaben ein\n");
scanf("%s", letter[0]); //Your chosen letter 
lpointer = strpbrk(var[0], letter[0]);  //letters been searched in the word 

if(lpointer != NULL)
{       
    while (lpointer != NULL)
        {
            k = lpointer - var[0];
            printf ("An der %d. Stelle gefunden\n",k+1);
            *p[k] = *lpointer; 
            lpointer = strpbrk(lpointer+1, letter[0]);
        }   


}   

        for(int w = 0; w < zeichen; w++)
 {
     printf("found letters: %c ", *p[w]);
 }
/*printf("Gefundene Buchstaben %c ", *p[0]);
fflush(stdout);
printf("%c ", *p[1]);
fflush(stdout);
printf("%c ", *p[2]);
fflush(stdout);
printf("%c ", *p[3]);
fflush(stdout);
printf("%c ", *p[4]);
fflush(stdout);*/


fflush(h);
fclose(h);



}   




int main (void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

Welcome();

showLogo();

RandomWords();


}
```

Comment: If you added some indentation, your code would be much easier to read. Anyway - what is the purpose of `p`? Why not have `strich` instead of `*p` ?

Comment: Week 3: Indention and code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
  ...
  char letter[2];  //found letter will be saved here
  int k = 0;  //position of the found letter in the word
              //char** position = calloc(zeichen, sizeof(char**));
  char* lpointer; //Addresse of the found letter 

  printf("\nGeben Sie bitte Ihren Buchstaben ein\n");
  scanf("%c", letter[0]); //Your chosen letter 
  letter[1] = 0;  // NUL terminator
  lpointer = strpbrk(var[0], letter);  //letters been searched in the word 

  if (lpointer != NULL)
  {
    while (lpointer != NULL)
    {
      k = lpointer - var[0];
      printf("An der %d. Stelle gefunden\n", k + 1);
      *p[k] = *lpointer;
      lpointer = strchr(lpointer + 1, letter[0]);
    }
  }
  ...
```

But there are most likely more problems elsewhere.

BTW: you should submit only "all English" programs, you will likely get more attention. But at least your variable names and comments are english.

And here you should check of `fopen` is successful:

```
FILE *h =  fopen("words.txt","r");
if (h == NULL)
{
  printf("Can't open words file\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

Comment: @4386427 because he's using it as a one letter NUL terminated string later on. Copy/paste corrected, thanks.

Comment: If you use `%c` you don't automatically get a null terminated string from `scanf`

Comment: @MichaelWalz Err, that's what I said. This naswer had `%c` in the scanf when I wrote the comment

Comment: @JeremyP forget my comment, I misread yours. Just corrected the code.

Comment: @4386427 rather `scanf("%1s", letter);`

Comment: You probably want `%1s` otherwise when I type `kflsjgkfds` at the prompt, it'll scribble all over memory.

Comment: So it's either `scanf("%c", letter[0]);   letter[1] = 0;` or `scanf("%1s", letter);`

Comment: why do i do strpbrk first then strchr?

Comment: @Furkano good question, there are probably more problems in that code.

Comment: Can my hdd cause problems since the error is due a memory issue? My hdd is quite old and had writing problems beforehand. Ill change my pc now to a linux one at our university, i hope that solves the problem. Otherwise i have to reedit my code.

Comment: @Furkano no, if your hdd had problems, there would be a lot of other things not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your `scanf` for the letter invokes undefined behaviour.

```
char* letter[1];
```

declares an unitinitialised array of one `char*`. Your `scanf` then tries to put the user input at the location pointed to by `letter[0]`. It's uninitialised so you could be putting the user input anywhere in memory.

In reality, the chances are it is a low number or even NULL or pointing to a bit of memory not allocated to your process yet. Either way, the likely result is a segmentation fault.

You need to allocate some storage to the string in which you want to put the input.

```
char letter[2]; // Room for one letter and a '\0'

scanf("%1s", letter); // Only scan one letter
```

`letter` can be used wherever `char*` is used as a string for example:

```
lpointer = strpbrk(lpointer+1, letter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only reading in one character you could do it like this instead

```
char letter;
scanf("%c", &letter); //Your chosen letter
if(isalpha(letter))
  {
  lpointer = strchr(var[0], letter);  //letters been searched in the word
```

The addition of the `isalpha()` condition will ensure that only letters of the alphabet are checked too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for so many ppl trying to help me out!

So i tried what you all said (except what chris turner proposed). But without any success.
Now i figured out that if i shorten the lenght of the arrays p and strich (strich is btw the underscores for each letter of the word) i can use more printfs and i dont get segmentation faults etc.
But the loop still doesnt want to work
If i add multiple printfs instead of looping that procedure, but as long as i use a loop to shorten that code, the execution stops after the letter input (scanf letter).